# NodeJS debugging not working with bot framework - Breakpoints not working

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to follow some tutorials, one is here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/Teams/20%20Messaging%20Extensions/Demos/01-msteams-msgext

The instructions for debugging basically say that I should have this in launch.json:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 5858,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
    ],
    "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"
}
```

I then run gulp serve --debug, but it's not launching in debug mode. Then I try hitting F5, but I get this:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Hi @M365 Dev, This can be fixed by changing Use Preview to disable in javascript debugger. 
Path:` VSCode > Setting > Workspace > Extension > Javascript debugger > Debug - Use Preview = Disable.`

Comment: please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Hi @Mamatha-MSFT I have tried this solution. didn't work for me. There's no well documented steps by Microsoft on how to setup debugging for teams bots, this is weird, it's all random posts on github but nothing official that actually works.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT any idea how this can be fixed?